# Multipart upload to Amazon Glacier: Content-Range incompatible with Content-Length

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to upload a file around 1gb in size to Amazon Glacier. Somewhat arbitrarily, I've decided to break it into 32mb parts and upload them in serial.

```py
import math
import boto3
from botocore.utils import calculate_tree_hash

client = boto3.client('glacier')
vault_name = 'my-vault'
size = 1073745600 # in bytes
size_mb = size / (2**20) # Convert to megabytes for readability
local_file = 'filename'

multi_up = client.initiate_multipart_upload(vaultName=vault_name,
                                        archiveDescription=local_file,
                                        partSize=str(2**25)) # 32 mb in bytes
parts = math.floor(size_mb / 32)
with open("/Users/alexchase/Desktop/{}".format(local_file), 'rb') as upload:
    for p in range(parts):
        # Calculate lower and upper bounds for the byte ranges. The last range
        # is bigger than the ones that come before.
        lower = (p * (2**25))
        upper = (((p + 1) * (2**25)) - 1) if (p + 1 < parts) else (size)
        up_part = client.upload_multipart_part(vaultName=vault_name,
                                           uploadId=multi_up['uploadId'],
                                           range='bytes {}-{}/*'.format(lower, upper),
                                           body=upload)
checksum = calculate_tree_hash(upload)
complete_up = client.complete_multipart_upload(archiveSize=str(size),
                                               checksum=checksum,
                                               uploadId=multi_up['uploadId'],
                                               vaultName=vault_name)
```

This generates an error about the first byte range.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidParameterValueException            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9dd3ac986601> in <module>()
     93                         uploadId=multi_up['uploadId'],
     94                         range='bytes {}-{}/*'.format(lower, upper),
---> 95                         body=upload)
     96                     upload_info.append(up_part)
     97                 checksum = calculate_tree_hash(upload)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    251                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    252             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 253             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    254
    255         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    555             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    556             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 557             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    558         else:
    559             return parsed_response

InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UploadMultipartPart operation:
Content-Range: bytes 0-33554431/* is incompatible with Content-Length: 1073745600
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Content-Range: bytes 0-33554431/* is incompatible with Content-Length: 1073745600
```

You're telling the API that you're sending the first 32 MiB, but you're actually sending (proposing to send) the entire file, since `body=upload` and `upload` isn't just the first part, it's the entire file.  The `Content-Length` refers to the size of this part upload, which should be 33554432 (32 MiB).

The [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#multipartupload) are admittedly ambiguous...

> `body` (bytes or seekable file-like object) -- The data to upload.

...but the "data to upload" seems to refer to the data for only this part, in spite of the word "seekable."

Answer (score 4):

@Michael-sqlbot is quite right, the issue with the `Content-Range` was that I was passing the whole file instead of a part. I fixed this by using the `read()` method, but then I discovered a separate issue, which is that (per the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/upload-multipart-part.html)), the final part has to be the same size or smaller than the preceding parts. This means using `math.ceil()` instead of `math.floor()` to define the number of parts.

The working code is:

```py
import math
import boto3
from botocore.utils import calculate_tree_hash

client = boto3.client('glacier')
vault_name = 'my-vault'
size = 1073745600 # in bytes
size_mb = size / (2**20) # Convert to megabytes for readability
local_file = 'filename'
partSize=(2**25)

multi_up = client.initiate_multipart_upload(vaultName=vault_name,
                                        archiveDescription=local_file,
                                        partSize=str(partSize)) # 32 mb in bytes
parts = math.ceil(size_mb / 32) # The number of <=32mb parts we need
with open("/Users/alexchase/Desktop/{}".format(local_file), 'rb') as upload:
    for p in range(parts):
        # Calculate lower and upper bounds for the byte ranges. The last range
        # is now smaller than the ones that come before.
        lower = (p * (partSize))
        upper = (((p + 1) * (partSize)) - 1) if (p + 1 < parts) else (size-1)
        read_size = upper-lower+1
        file_part = upload.read(read_size)
        up_part = client.upload_multipart_part(vaultName=vault_name,
                                           uploadId=multi_up['uploadId'],
                                           range='bytes {}-{}/*'.format(lower, upper),
                                           body=file_part)
checksum = calculate_tree_hash(upload)
complete_up = client.complete_multipart_upload(archiveSize=str(size),
                                               checksum=checksum,
                                               uploadId=multi_up['uploadId'],
                                               vaultName=vault_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the follow up answer from Alex claims it "works", I'm posting another version that worked for me under Python 3.5 and Ubuntu 16.04. I also added some environment variables from our production end to end solution.

The original post gave me an error so I tweaked it and provided some clean up. Hope this helps someone needing this Glacier functionality. Using a Shell script with awscli commands was not as clean.

```
import math
import boto3
import os
from botocore.utils import calculate_tree_hash

vault_name = os.getenv('GLACIER_VAULT_NAME')
file_name = os.getenv('GLACIER_UPLOAD_FILE')

if vault_name is None:
    print('GLACIER_VAULT_NAME environment variable is required. Exiting.')
    exit(1)
if file_name is None:
    print('GLACIER_UPLOAD_FILE environment variable is required. Exiting.')
    exit(2)

chunk_size = 2 ** 25
client = boto3.client('glacier')

client.create_vault(vaultName=vault_name)

upload_obj = client.initiate_multipart_upload(vaultName=vault_name,
                                              archiveDescription=file_name,
                                              partSize=str(chunk_size))
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
parts = math.ceil(file_size / chunk_size)

with open(file_name, 'rb') as upload:
    for p in range(parts):
        lower = p * chunk_size
        upper = lower + chunk_size - 1

        if upper > file_size:
            upper = (file_size - lower) + lower - 1

        file_part = upload.read(chunk_size)

        up_part = client.upload_multipart_part(vaultName=vault_name,
                                               uploadId=upload_obj['uploadId'],
                                               range='bytes {}-{}/{}'.format(lower,
                                                                             upper,
                                                                             file_size),
                                               body=file_part)

# this needs a new file handler because calculate_tree_hash() processes 
# the handler in a similar way to the loop above
checksum = calculate_tree_hash(open(file_name, 'rb'))
complete_up = client.complete_multipart_upload(vaultName=vault_name,
                                               uploadId=upload_obj['uploadId'],
                                               archiveSize=str(file_size),
                                               checksum=checksum)

print(complete_up)
```